# Is there any practical use for jumping?

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

When roaming around the Grymoire, you can perform a very small jump/hop by pressing the circle button.

Does this have any use throughout the game, or is it just for fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since completed the game included all post-game dungeons and there has never been a requirement for me to use the jump ability. Furthermore, none of the tutorials mention using the jump ability for any specific purpose.

So with that in mind, I believe it is reasonable to conclude that there is no practical use for the jump ability. Other than to spice things up when you are walking a tediously long path that is.